# Android VideoView orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation, android-videoview

I am having a `VideoView` playing video on my Android app. When I try it on the portrait orientation, the video fills the screen. But when I change the orientation to landscape, the video takes up only half the screen space. I am using `FILL_PARENT`, `FILL_PARENT` as the layout parameters.

Is there a way I can have the video fill the screen in both orientations?

Comment: Is there letterboxing -- i.e. black bars to each side of the video? If this is what you're trying to avoid, you may want to use a `MediaPlayer`/`SurfaceView` combination for more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video might be just too small. You can center it in parent to make it look better. Or try to request bigger video from your provider.

Answer (score 2):

If it fills the screen perfectly in portrait mode how will it ever fit perfectly in landscape mode without changing the aspect ratio?

The same goes for the reverse - if it fits perfectly in landscape mode, when you change to portrait it won't take up all the vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider making two different layouts for portrait and landscape views.
Let's assume you have "/res/layout/main.xml" file. In the "/res/" folder make a child folder and name it "layout-land", the R file is going to be automatically generated! 
Here is a snapshot just to make it easier...

[alt text http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/5749/previewu.png](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/5749/previewu.png)

after you can edit each layout independently... 
This is the most common way of working with orientation change, when it comes to layouts.

Best regards,

Igor